# Excel VBA - Send MailMerge to the Printer

Tags: excel, ms-word, word-field, vba

I want to expand on the functionality related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357121/executing-word-mail-merge-from-excel-macro). Is there anyway to set it up to send the `MailMerge` to the printer rather than create a new file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could use the same code as listed in your link, but then add a line to print the resulting word doc.  I'm not familiar with the word syntax, but this should work (or at least get you started).

Replace:

```
wd.Visible = True
wdocSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

With:

```
wd.Visible = True
wdocSource.print
wdocSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
```