# VBA - Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: vba, object, excel

I am receiving the error **"Object doesn't support this property or method"**,  in Excel after I changed part of my code. The line that is throwing the error is **"With odoc.MailMerge"** Here is the code:

```
  strBookName = "\" & "PM MailMerge.xlsm"
  strBookPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
  strBook = strBookPath & strBookName

'Opens Word.Application

  Set ObjWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  Set odoc = GetObject(strBook)

'Executes a Hidden Mail Merge

  ObjWord.Visible = False
  With odoc.MailMerge
  .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
  With .DataSource
  .FirstRecord = 1
  .LastRecord = 1
   odoc.MailMerge.Execute
   Set odoc2 = odoc.Application.documents("Form Letters1")
   odoc.Close True
End With
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
option explicit

Dim objWord as Word.Application
Dim oDoc as As Word.Document

Set ObjWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
set oDoc = objWord.documents.Open strBook
```

Don't forget to reference the Word library in the menu: tools > references.

By the way: Dim all your variables (force with option explicit).

Edit: 
Note: the file that you mention in your code sample is an Excel .xlsm, not a Word .doc...

Answer (score 0):

Set odoc = GetObject(strBook) is this a workbook for excel?  if so there is no MailMerge method for a workbook object.  You need to reference a word document to use the MailMerge Method of the Document objet

Comment: Yes it is an excel workbook. The only part I have changed in my code was the **"Set odoc="** and then it stopped working

Comment: Here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357121/executing-word-mail-merge/10188431#10188431